# How to quickly jump from one entry box to another?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to quickly jump from one input box to another? For example, in the retopoflow menu, is there a way to go from the source object to the target object box with a button instead of manually clicking it? Usually you could use tab for things like this online but it doesn't seem to work in this case. I was just curious because I'm trying to speed up my workflow for retopology with many objects.

[image: menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eyedropper button next to each setting activates an operator, which means you can connect it to a keyboard shortcut.

In the [preferences under Input](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/input.html) you can add a new keyboard shortcut. I would suggest adding it under *3DView/ObjectMode*. By scrolling down to the bottom you will find an *Add New* button which you click and then you fill in the details.

For the operator name, which starts as none, enter `cgcookie.eye_dropper`, then the `target_property` will become available where you enter `source_object` to set the source and `target_object` for the target. Then choose the shortcut settings you want to use for each. By clicking the [Save User Settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/introduction.html#save-user-settings) button, the shortcut will be available every time you start blender.

Here I set <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to set the source object and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to select the target object.

[image: shortcut for eye dropper]

Now you can press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> and click an object to set it as the source object and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to choose the target object.